# Google Quotas on Reads/Writes with V4, no of Spreadsheets and FileSize restriction

Tags: google-sheets-api

Google documentation doesn't detail the limits imposed on read/write.

Google in this link https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits talks about limits on reads and writes but doesn't talk about exact limits in data terms. Also are there any limits imposed in creating new spreadsheets? Can I create as many spreadsheets as I want? There is no documentation available on the same. Are there any file size restrictions on the google sheets imposed.

Comment: Of course there are restrictions. Creating files in Drive falls under the Drive API.